# Throwing correct response from the web service when fiddler4 is opened

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

I have a requirement to check the VAT ID and the web service is "[http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService][1]"
I have added a web service reference to my ASP.NET project and tried to access the web service.I am also tracking the network using Fiddler4.Surprisingly, when Fiddler was opened response from the web service is absolutely correct and If Fiddler was not launched  the response from the web service is wrong.Can anyone have any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Can you please update your question with details on how **exactly** the response is "wrong"? What does a "correct" response look like, and what does the "incorrect" response look like?

Comment: @EricLaw: When  we enter a valid VAT ID details,the correct response would be company name,address.If VAT ID details are wrong it would display "Invalid vat id"  message. Now my problem here is,though i entered the correct vat id details it was displayed "Invalid vat id" message.After launching fiddler if we try to validate the same it was displayed the company name and address details.

Comment: Can you share a `SAZ` file from Fiddler (send to me via Help > Send Feedback) demonstrating the issue?